# Timestamp for Ethernet frames

Tags: sockets, socketcan, stream-socket-client

I am receiving CAN and Ethernet messages I would like to compare  them according to timestamp.
i am using socket CAN  and "ioctl(s, SIOCGSTAMP, &tv);" function to get timestamp for can frames and it works great;where s is the socket of can
but when i use it for ethernet frames it gives a negative value sometimes but more importantly each timestamp is the same ,what might be wrong?